# API error code 191. redirect_uri is not owned by de application. Mobile app

Tags: facebook, html, mobile

I'm trying to connect my mobile app with facebook. I develop my app in HTML5 and JS.

I'm not sure what settings I must to specify in my app.dashboard. What url's I have to put in:

Site url and Mobile Site url?

My code is:

FB.init({appId : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                status : true,
                xfbml : true
            });

and the error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.